# Python date string in a variable

Tags: python, string, date, compare

I have done the following
read in a csv file and capture the date in a cell to create a variable `created`
next read from the csv file and capture the date in another cell to create a variable `resolved`
I take the value in the created date field and add 8 hours to get a variable `breached`

the value in created and resolved has this format `12/1/2020 17:19` and the value in breached
is `2020-12-02 01:19:00`

how do I format the breached variable to match the created/resolved variable? so I can see if the breach time is less than the resolved time

Comment: What data type are you storing the dates as in your code? How are you formatting them as strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `datetime` library to parse the date time string and then use `timedelta` to add 8 hours to the datetime.

**If you use Windows, you can use the following code:**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

created_date = datetime.strptime("12/1/2020 17:19", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
breached_date = created_date + timedelta(hours=8)
breached_date_formatted = breached_date.strftime("%#m/%#d/%Y %H:%M")
```

**If you use Linux, you can use the following code:**

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

created_date = datetime.strptime("12/1/2020 17:19", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
breached_date = created_date + timedelta(hours=8)
breached_date_formatted = breached_date.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert python date strings you can use `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime("2020-12-02 01:19:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(datetime_object)
```

Output:

```
02/12/2020 01:19
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my issue.